# My textbook claims that base kW = base kVA, but doesn't this equality break down when power factor isn't zero?

Tags: circuit-analysis, basic

I am new to per unit quantities, and have tried various combinations of search terms on Google over the span of a week and a half but I'm finding myself still stuck.

In the SI edition of Power Systems Analysis by Grainger/Stevenson/Chang, the authors present a list of formulas (p42) that relate various base quantities for single-phase systems. All of them make sense to me except the ones encircled in red.

kW = kVA holds true only when power factor is zero right? Surely this equality does not hold in general for single-phase systems? Why is this formula in this list at all?

[image: Equations 2.48 & 2.49 on p42 of Grainger/Steven/Chang]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are correct that KW only equals KVA when power factor is 1.  They are not suggesting otherwise.

The text is just telling you that the **base** for \$KW_{pu}\$ and  \$KVA_{pu}\$ is the same numerical value.  Just like the impedance base is the same numerical value for resistance, \$R_{pu}\$, as it is for reactance, \$X_{pu}\$.

Comment: My original comment didn't go through -- thank you for understanding my question and helping me out here relayman

Comment: You are very welcome.